# Filtering an array with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got two arrays with some objects which I receive from API calls.

I need to combine those in one single array, but some objects are in different states on my app. So, if the objects in both array got the same "Code" attribute, I need to keep the one with more information.

I tried to make and nested loop (yeah, from what I read it's a poor technique, but I will never get more than 5 items at the same time). Then I tried to compare both "code objects", and push the equal results on a new array, which works fine. When I try to use a second condition on the same loop, it just doesn't work.

```js
let array1 = [{
    'DataCad': "2019-01-04T15:04:02.663",
    'Field1': "rt",
    'Code': "DFG3456",
  },
  {
    'DataCad': "2019-01-07T11:37:31.8",
    'Field1': "TESTE2",
    'Code': "TYU1235",
  },
  {
    'DataCad': "2019-01-07T13:15:48.97",
    'Field1': "Uppercase",
    'Code': "JJJ1212",
  },
  {
    'DataCad': "2019-01-07T16:35:32.697",
    'Field1': "234",
    'Code': "OOO1111",
  },
  {
    'DataCad': "2019-01-07T10:46:46.437",
    'Field1': "TESTE1",
    'Code': "GHJ1234",
  }
]

let array2 = [{
    'DataAge': "2019-01-07",
    'DataCad': "2019-01-04T15:04:49.05",
    'HoraAge': "12:25",
    'Field1': "rt",
    'Pag': "N",
    'Code': "DFG3456",
  },
  {
    'DataAge': "2019-01-07",
    'DataCad': "2019-01-07T11:17:57.583",
    'HoraAge': "13:15",
    'Field1': "TESTE1",
    'Pag': "N",
    'Code': "GHJ1234",
  },
  {
    'DataAge': "2019-01-08",
    'DataCad': "2019-01-07T11:38:46.08",
    'HoraAge': "10:15",
    'Field1': "TESTE2",
    'Pag': "N",
    'Code': "TYU1235",
  },
  {
    'DataAge': "2020-01-7 ",
    'DataCad': "2019-01-07T13:16:00.567",
    'HoraAge': "15:15",
    'Field1': "Uppercase",
    'Pag': "N",
    'Code': "JJJ1212",
  }
]

let finalArray = [];


for (var i in array1) {

  for (var j in array2) {
    if (array1[i].Code == array2[j].Code && !array1[i].DataAge) {
      finalArray.push(array1[i].Code)
    }
  }
}

console.log(finalArray);
}
```

Need to get one single array with those filtered results. Is there a better solution?

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: What do you mean by `more information`, like more properties? What if two items have the same number of properties and same code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `map` method by passing a provided *callback* function as argument which is applied for every item from your given array.

Also, use `find` method in order to make `Code` property matching.

> I need to keep the one with more information.

Use `Object.keys` method in order to decide which object contains more information.

```js
let array1 = [ { 'DataCad': "2019-01-04T15:04:02.663", 'Field1': "rt", 'Code': "DFG3456", }, { 'DataCad': "2019-01-07T11:37:31.8", 'Field1': "TESTE2", 'Code': "TYU1235", }, { 'DataCad': "2019-01-07T13:15:48.97", 'Field1': "Uppercase", 'Code': "JJJ1212", }, { 'DataCad': "2019-01-07T16:35:32.697", 'Field1': "234", 'Code': "OOO1111", } , { 'DataCad': "2019-01-07T10:46:46.437", 'Field1': "TESTE1", 'Code': "GHJ1234", } ]

let array2 = [ { 'DataAge': "2019-01-07", 'DataCad': "2019-01-04T15:04:49.05", 'HoraAge': "12:25", 'Field1': "rt", 'Pag': "N", 'Code': "DFG3456", }, { 'DataAge': "2019-01-07", 'DataCad': "2019-01-07T11:17:57.583", 'HoraAge': "13:15", 'Field1': "TESTE1", 'Pag': "N", 'Code': "GHJ1234", }, { 'DataAge': "2019-01-08", 'DataCad': "2019-01-07T11:38:46.08", 'HoraAge': "10:15", 'Field1': "TESTE2", 'Pag': "N", 'Code': "TYU1235", }, { 'DataAge': "2020-01-7 ", 'DataCad': "2019-01-07T13:16:00.567", 'HoraAge': "15:15", 'Field1': "Uppercase", 'Pag': "N", 'Code': "JJJ1212", } ]

let finalArray = array1.map(function(item){
   let foundItem = array2.find(({Code}) => Code == item.Code);
   if(foundItem)
      return Object.keys(item).length > Object.keys(foundItem).length ? item : foundItem;
   return item;
});
console.log(finalArray);
```

Here's a short hand and slightly more functional approach too, this approach makes use of techniques such as currying and whatnot, if you'd like to look into functional programming, maybe look up [Eric Elliot](https://medium.com/@_ericelliott).

```js
let array1 = [ { 'DataCad': "2019-01-04T15:04:02.663", 'Field1': "rt", 'Code': "DFG3456", }, { 'DataCad': "2019-01-07T11:37:31.8", 'Field1': "TESTE2", 'Code': "TYU1235", }, { 'DataCad': "2019-01-07T13:15:48.97", 'Field1': "Uppercase", 'Code': "JJJ1212", }, { 'DataCad': "2019-01-07T16:35:32.697", 'Field1': "234", 'Code': "OOO1111", } , { 'DataCad': "2019-01-07T10:46:46.437", 'Field1': "TESTE1", 'Code': "GHJ1234", } ]

let array2 = [ { 'DataAge': "2019-01-07", 'DataCad': "2019-01-04T15:04:49.05", 'HoraAge': "12:25", 'Field1': "rt", 'Pag': "N", 'Code': "DFG3456", }, { 'DataAge': "2019-01-07", 'DataCad': "2019-01-07T11:17:57.583", 'HoraAge': "13:15", 'Field1': "TESTE1", 'Pag': "N", 'Code': "GHJ1234", }, { 'DataAge': "2019-01-08", 'DataCad': "2019-01-07T11:38:46.08", 'HoraAge': "10:15", 'Field1': "TESTE2", 'Pag': "N", 'Code': "TYU1235", }, { 'DataAge': "2020-01-7 ", 'DataCad': "2019-01-07T13:16:00.567", 'HoraAge': "15:15", 'Field1': "Uppercase", 'Pag': "N", 'Code': "JJJ1212", } ];

// Finds an object in the givne array based on the code property. 
let find = i => a => a.find(({Code}) => Code == i.Code)

// Returns the object with more keys.
let longer = i => o => Object.keys(i).length > Object.keys(o).length ? i : o;

// Returns the relevant array of objects.
let filter = a1 => a2 => a1.map(i => find(i)(a2) ? longer(i)(find(i)(a2)) :  i);

// Fire the filter function.
let finalArray = filter(array1)(array2);

console.log(finalArray); // Log it!
```

Comment: it worked. Thanks! I will study the map function now, so I can apply it if needed again in the future! ;)

Comment: @cfnerd I made a mistake with the initial edit I made, I've updated it, I forgot to pass the array to the `find` function... My bad!

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut It's quite alright, as I'm quite new to this game myself, I do a hell of a lot of reading into articles by well regarded developers, such as Eric, and I find him to be an excellent source for functional-style JavaScript, so I thought why not share what I've been learning recently...

Answer (score 0):

You can iteterate over `array1` and `find` the matching element in `array2` and then push the element with more information (with more number of properties) in your final array.

```
let finalArray = [];

let array1 = [
    {
        'DataCad': "2019-01-04T15:04:02.663",
        'Field1': "rt",
        'Code': "DFG3456",
    },
    {
        'DataCad': "2019-01-07T11:37:31.8",
        'Field1': "TESTE2",
        'Code': "TYU1235",
    },
    {
        'DataCad': "2019-01-07T13:15:48.97",
        'Field1': "Uppercase",
        'Code': "JJJ1212",
    },
    {
        'DataCad': "2019-01-07T16:35:32.697",
        'Field1': "234",
        'Code': "OOO1111",
    },
    {
        'DataCad': "2019-01-07T10:46:46.437",
        'Field1': "TESTE1",
        'Code': "GHJ1234",
    }
]

let array2 = [
    {
        'DataAge': "2019-01-07",
        'DataCad': "2019-01-04T15:04:49.05",
        'HoraAge': "12:25",
        'Field1': "rt",
        'Pag': "N",
        'Code': "DFG3456",
    },
    {
        'DataAge': "2019-01-07",
        'DataCad': "2019-01-07T11:17:57.583",
        'HoraAge': "13:15",
        'Field1': "TESTE1",
        'Pag': "N",
        'Code': "GHJ1234",
    },
    {
        'DataAge': "2019-01-08",
        'DataCad': "2019-01-07T11:38:46.08",
        'HoraAge': "10:15",
        'Field1': "TESTE2",
        'Pag': "N",
        'Code': "TYU1235",
    },
    {
        'DataAge': "2020-01-7 ",
        'DataCad': "2019-01-07T13:16:00.567",
        'HoraAge': "15:15",
        'Field1': "Uppercase",
        'Pag': "N",
        'Code': "JJJ1212",
    }
]

array1.forEach(function (element1) {
    var found = array2.find(function (element2) {
        return element2.Code == element1.Code;
    });
    if (found) {
        var requiredElement = Object.keys(element1).length > Object.keys(found).length ? element1 : found;
        finalArray.push(requiredElement);
    }
});
console.log(finalArray);
```